# Is it possible to get user uid in login form submit in DrupalGap?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have altered the login form like

```
if (form_id == 'user_login_form') {
    form.submit.push('my_module_user_login_submit');
  }
```

In submit I need the uid.

```
function my_module_user_login_submit(form, form_state) {
   //I need the uid of login user here;
  if(form_state.values.name){
   form.action = 'user-dashboard/'+ uid;
   }
}
```

Tried

**var uid = Drupal.user.uid;** but not working.

More info

```
function my_module_menu() {
var items = {};
items['user-dashboard/%'] = {
    title: 'User dashboard',
    page_callback: 'my_module_user_dashboard_page',
    page_arguments: [1],
    pageshow: 'my_module_user_dashboard_pageshow'
  };
return items;
}


**
 * The user dashboard page callback.
 * @param uid
 * @returns {{}}
 */
function my_module_user_dashboard_page(uid) {
  var content = {};

  // Build an empty container where the user dashboard will go.
  var attributes = {
    id: my_module_user_dashboard_container_id(uid),
    class: 'user-dashboard'
  };
  content['my_widget_container'] = {
    markup: '<div ' + drupalgap_attributes(attributes) + '>' +
      'Loading dashboard...' +
    '</div>'
  };

  return content;
}

/**
 * The user dashboard pageshow event handler.
 * @param uid
 */
function my_module_user_dashboard_pageshow(uid) {
alert(Drupal.user.uid);
  // Load the user account...
  user_load(uid, {
    success: function(account) {
    var content = {};
    content['txt'] = {
        markup: '<div>' + account.name + '</div><div>' + account.uid + '</div>'
    };



      // Inject it into the container.
      var container_id = my_module_user_dashboard_container_id(uid);
      $('#' + container_id).html(drupalgap_render(content)).trigger('create');

    }
  });
}

function my_module_user_dashboard_container_id(uid) {
  return 'user-dashboard-' + uid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this hook in your app: http://api.drupalgap.org/7/global.html#hook_services_postprocess

```
/**
 * Implements hook_services_postprocess().
 */
function my_module_services_postprocess(options, result) {
  if (options.service == 'user' && options.resource == 'login') {
    drupalgap_goto('user-dashboard/'+ Drupal.user.uid);
  }
}
```

You may also need to set the `action` on the form object to `null` so that DrupalGap core doesn't try to redirect the page to the path indicated by the form's `action` variable:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(form, form_state, form_id) {
  if (form_id == 'user_login_form') {
    form.action = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using a `hook_form_alter()` in DrupalGap to set the `action` on the form to `null`.

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer with an example of `hook_form_alter()`.